# "Invalid profile: The PayloadUUID '....' is used more than once in the profile

Tags: ios, installation, beta

Trying to install iOS_beta_Profile.mobileconfig but get "Invalid profile: The PayloadUUID '....' is used more than once in the profile.

The phone is registered as a dev device with the latest beta version of XCode. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Usually this error message pops up if you are trying to download iOS from macOS. So tap that same link from an iPad instead of on macOS, or choose the iTunes-based download method (iOS Restore Images), and upgrade from iTunes.